# Can brown from NM 6/2 be used as hot in electrical panel?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

Planning to use NM 6/2 for a hardwired EVSE. It comes with black, brown, and white. Can I use the brown as hot in the electrical panel as is? Or do I need to tape it black?

[image]

Comment: I think it is a bad picture colouring.  /2 cables have black, white and ground(bare or green cover).  Not brown.   If the device(EVSE, heater) does not use neutral, then you can mark white with red or black tape for the second hot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cant use that particular wire in the way you describe.
The NM-B cable you show there has Black, White & bare ground wires contained in it.
The center conductor in that pic is a bare ground wire wrapped in a layer of brown(ish) paper, not brown insulation.
Take a look at the pic more carefully and you'll see that the brown layer around the center conductor is exactly the same color *and thickness* as the brown layer wrapped around all 3 wires.
It's paper, not insulation, so you can't re-mark and use it as a hot (or even a neutral).

Comment: Oh yes you are right. EVSE needs 2 hots and 1 ground. I just need to mark the white as hot then.

Comment: @user162793 yes, since you don't need neutral, just mark white as hot.

Answer (score 2):

The "brown" wire is an uninsulated ground wire.  The brown stuff in the picture is paper, around the ground and between the wires and outer jacket.  Southwire creates its CGI product photography this way.   For your intended use, you use the black and (marked) white as hots and the ground as ground ... exactly as intended.

Answer (score 2):

### It's not brown. It's bare copper ground.

> Planning to use NM 6/2 for a hardwired EVSE. It comes with black, brown, and white.

Fake news. It's a bad Photoshop.  The third wire in NM cable is actually bare ground.

NM and UF have a thermal disadvantage that requires larger wire for the same ampacity.  #6 NM is only 55A wire which means you must set the EVSE for 50A breaker not 60A.* In other types such as SEU or SER cable, #8 copper is 50A, and #6 copper is 65A. SER has a separate neutral and ground.

If you're going to a 50A socket, you need neutral if the socket needs it, but since most sockets accept AL wire, use #6 aluminum SER at 50A.

### We've had the ampacity conversation, right?

You do not need to run cable for the maximum an EVSE is capable of, if it has DIP switches or a setup procedure to set breaker size, and most do.  In practice, 50-60A [is bonkers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iyp_X3mwE1w&t=1695s) for charging an EV, unless it's a hotel or AirBnB where travelers will be refilling after a 200+ mile drive.  Cars are reducing their support for >30-40A breakers anyway, as the on-car equipment is costly and it's rarely used productively.

* A #6 NM circuit is a 55A circuit. Code has the "Round Up rule" which says if a given breaker size is not manufactured, you can use the next size up breaker. However this is *not* license to say 60A when the EVSE setup procedure asks breaker size.  Since that is an actual load, you must round *down*.

Comment: The picture was confusing. I picked up the cable from Lowe's earlier and yes it's bare ground with brown paper. I'm planning to install the Wallbox Pulsar Plus 40A hardwired with this cable with a 50A breaker. I'm planning to keep the dip stitches at the default 40A even though my car only draws up to 30A just in case any guests need it. I plan to load shed the EVSE pairing it with their Wallbox energy meter. Based on my load calculations I could only go with load shedding or dryer splitter.

Comment: @user162793 dead nuts perfect... you should teach that material lol.

Answer (score -2):

As long as it's not white, green or bare, yes. But why worry about it, just tape it black to be sure, it's about a penny's worth of tape.

Comment: This would be relevant if the wire in question were actually insulated brown, but it’s not.